# ¿Cómo recortar un texto cuando no haya espacio y poner al final puntos suspensivos si continua?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

He estado intentando hacer que mi placeholder se vea recortado con puntos suspensivos al exceder el espacio que le doy pero no lo consigo.

```
.prueba{
  border: solid 2px blue;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

<div className='prueba' key={data.code}>
  <TextField
    label={`${data.name}`}
    onChange={handleConfigurationTextChange(data.code)}
  />
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Por que en el html tienes un `className`? No deberia ser solo `class` ???

Comment: el className es porque así funciona en React. Y lo que se me muestra son las dos imágenes de abajo

Comment: No conozco React, pero si a ese elemento **TextField** le puedes agregar esa clase **prueba** (o sea, un `className='prueba'`) en lugar del div superior, deberia funcionarte bien

Comment: Me muestra el mismo resultado que poniendo la clase en el div

Comment: ¿Puedes poner en la pregunta el código HTML que eso te genera en la salida? ¿O no se puede ver?  Si eso va a una página web lo puedes mirar pulsando el botón derecho sobre el elemento y seleccionando "Inspeccionar" en el menú contextual que aparece en tu navegador. Lo copias de allí y lo pegas en la pregunta para que podamos ayudarte mejor, pues ahora no se si te está creando un textarea o un input, pero en ambos he hecho pruebas y deberia funcionarte (al menos en html puro, que entiendo que React lo convierte a eso supongo)

Comment: @masterguru creo que he añadido lo que me comentas

Comment: Si, ahora lo veo, vaya vaya con el react este... pone elementos por doquier, je... y no usa el atributo **placeholder** en el **input** como esperaba, lo pone en un **label**... prueba de cambiar esto: `.prueba{`  por esto `.prueba > label {` y a ver si suena la campana y tenemos suerte

Comment: No ha servido, muchas gracias por tu ayuda ya ha comentado un muchacho en las respuestas el como hacerlo

Comment: Si, bueno, tambien he puesto mi respuesta completa por si acaso te sirve algo mejor. Al final he probado un editor de React para verlo "in situ" y de ese modo es como mejor lo he visto, pero tu sabrás en tu caso concreto lo que mejor te ha ido. Tal como dice @Excorpion, recuerda marcar la respuesta que más te ha ayudado para que la pregunta no quede eternamente pendiente. También léete [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y el porque es importante aceptar las respuestas válidas. Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Añadí un `display: block` al nuevo código que pegaste, y probé con `.prueba label` en la clase CSS.

Lo que no se, es si es necesario el `float: left`, dado que cambia la disposición del resto de las cosas, pero seguro puedes corregir eso tu.

Saqué la guía a partir de esta respuesta, por si la quieres revisar: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779293/css-text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working

```css
.prueba label{
  border: solid 2px blue;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="prueba">
  <div class="MuiFormControl-root-15">
    <label class="MuiFormLabel-root-130 MuiInputLabel-root-119 MuiInputLabel-formControl-124 MuiInputLabel-animated-127" data-shrink="false">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</label>
    <div class="MuiInputBase-root-32 MuiInput-root-19 MuiInput-underline-23 MuiInputBase-formControl-33 MuiInput-formControl-20">
      <input aria-invalid="false" class="MuiInputBase-input-42 MuiInput-input-27" type="text" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ya lo he conseguido, muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Si te ha servido, recuerda marcar la respuesta y asi queda la publicacion cerrada